# Thymeleaf Spring weblow ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-webflow-2, thymeleaf

I am trying to make my first ajax call / response with Spring webflow, and response rendered with thymeleaf. I have used thymeleaf example from their pdf Thymeleaf + Spring 3.

flow config:

```
<view-state id="detail" view="bookingDetail"> 
<transitionon="updateData">
<render fragments="hoteldata"/>
</transition>
</view-state>
```

my html:

```
<div id="data" th:fragment="hoteldata">
This is a content to be changed
</div>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/dojo/dojo.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/spring/Spring.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js}"></script>
...
<form id="triggerform" method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" id="doUpdate" name="_eventId_updateData" value="Update now!" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
Spring.addDecoration(
new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({formId:'triggerform',elementId:'doUpdate',event:'onclick'}));
</script>
```

First I disable submit with:

```
 <input type="submit" id="doUpdate" name="_eventId_activeOrders" value="Update now!" onclick="return false;"/>
```

to prevent whole page reload.

In logs I see that action is executed by SpringWebflow and then I see :

Chrome Js console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of null Spring-Dojo.js:16
dojo.declare.submitForm Spring-Dojo.js:16
dojo.declare.submit Spring-Dojo.js:16
dojo.hitch
```

or Firefox console:

```
TypeError: _1a is null
http://localhost:9092/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js
Line 16
```

I am not sure how to proceed or where to start search problems. Anybody have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly looks as a javascript problem, as if DOJO isn't finding your `triggerform` form tag (it's looking for its `method` attribute but says the form object is null)...

Could it be that your `activeOrders` transition is actually modifying that form and removing it, or maybe outputting different HTML for it than the one you show here? I'd suggest trying without the "activeOrders" event part.

And btw, you have a misspelled `transitionon` attribute in your SWF configuration (should be `transition on`)

Comment: Thanks, there was some javascript changing all forms id to formSomeNumebr. Now there is other problems, but that would duplicate other stackoverflow questions.